# How to import data in .cypherl format to a Memgraph that runs in Docker?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a Memgraph installed using docker. I didn't use Memgraph Platform docker image, so I don't have a Memgraph Lab.

I have data in `.cypherl` format. How can I import it into Memgraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact procedure/command depends on your operating system. If you are using Linux or macOS your command would be:

```
docker run -i --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph/memgraph-platform --host HOST < queries.cypherl
```

If you are running Docker under Windows then the command is:

```
cmd.exe /c "docker run -i --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph/memgraph-platform --host HOST < queries.cypherl"
```

Be sure to replace `HOST` with valid IP of the container and to define the correct Memgraph Docker image you are using as well as the correct path to the file.